# Загрузить файл на FTP сервер по URL ссылке, C#

Tags: c#, url, ftp

Мне необходимо загрузить файл на FTP сервер по имеющейся URL ссылке на этот файл(используя C#). Например, картинка http://www.fingus.ru/pict/pict1003/kartinki_987787543333333.jpg 
Есть ли способ (библиотека, скрипт), которая позволит мне загрузить эту картинку сразу на FTP, не скачивая промежуточно ее себе на компьютер?

Answer (score 3):

Нет. FTP в принципе не умеет вытягивать файл по ссылке.

Comment: Здравствуйте, может вы сможете подсказать по моей похожей проблеме: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/795261/c-ftp-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8