# C# ftp загрузка файлов из директории

Tags: c#, ftp

Как реализовать функцию загрузки всех файлов из X директории в Y директорию на ftp.

Я добился, что отправляется один файл. Но есть две проблемы:

1 В директорие очень много файлов под директорий.

2 Если файл уже есть с таким именем, надо затирать новым файлом.

```
            requestFTPUploader = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://127.0.0.1/Destination/" + fileName);
            requestFTPUploader.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
            requestFTPUploader.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filepath);
            FileStream fileStream = fileInfo.OpenRead();

            int bufferLength = 2048;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];

            try
            {
                Stream uploadStream = requestFTPUploader.GetRequestStream();
                int contentLength = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);

                while (contentLength != 0)
                {
                    uploadStream.Write(buffer, 0, contentLength);
                    contentLength = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                }

                uploadStream.Close();
                fileStream.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.Message.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine(fileName + "Uploaded");
```

Т.е. нужна функция со входящими параметрами: user, pass, sourceDir, destinationDir. А на выходе скопированные/замещённые файлы на сервер по протоколу ftp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Очень много файлов? Ну хорошо, значит, будет долго копироваться. Это ведь не проблема?
2. Используйте `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile`:

   ```
   var requestFtpDeleter = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
                                           "ftp://127.0.0.1/Destination/" + fileName);
   requestFtpDeleter.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
   requestFtpDeleter.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;
   using (var response = (FtpWebResponse)requestFtpDeleter.GetResponse())
   {
       bool isSuccessful = response.StatusCode >= 200 && response.StatusCode < 300;
       // исключение при ошибке?
   }
   ```

Comment: Другими словами вы предлагаете сначала удалить все файлы, а потом залить новые? Это конечно выход, но он мне не нравится. Кроме того, это не рабочий вариант так как, есть часть файлов, которые не связаны с проектом, но они лежат тут и будут удалены. Плюсик поставил. :)

Comment: @Anonymous: Нет, конечно, не все. Только те файлы, которые вы хотите записать, а вам ответили, что такой файл уже есть. Тогда существующий файл нужно удалить, и при успехе попробовать записать снова.

Comment: А например клиент WinSCP, так же работает? Каждый файл отдельно рассматривает?

Comment: @Anonymous: А вы посмотрите в протокол FTP, есть ли в нём пакетная передача файлов. Я не нашёл.

Comment: В конечном итоге, реализовал так как написал  @VladD, сначала сравниваем есть ли файл, потом удаляем, потом записываем этот файл заново.